# MapServer HTML Legend How-to

Tags: error, legend, mapserver, mapfile

I am trying to build my first HTML legend with MapServer, but I can't find any full example.

As I understand:

mylayer.map (just after the classes END):

```
LEGEND
    TEMPLATE "../path/mylegend.html"  ### HTML template file
END
```

mylegend.html:

```
<B>Legend</B><BR><HR>[legend]<HR>
```

mylegend.map:

```
[legend]
[leg_class_html opt_flag=15]
   <img src=[leg_icon]> [leg_class_name]<br>
[/leg_class_html]
[/legend]
```

Comment: There seems to be a HTML legend demo at https://demo.mapserver.org/itasca_legend/, maybe it helps.

Comment: Thank you, it is hepful! I am not sure where the legend code should go? In the mylegend.html file or an adjacent mylegend.map file ?

Comment: Yes, I had created and updated the HTML Legend demo earlier today for you (and replied to you on the -users list, but didn't realize that you posted this question in multiple locations), hope it helps!  Let me know if it needs enhancements.  Thanks again!  (you can find all of the demos listed at https://demo.mapserver.org )  Thanks for mapserv-ing!  -jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created and maintain the official HTML Legend demo for MapServer, and you can find all of the examples at https://demo.mapserver.org/itasca_legend/  (I had updated it all this morning, when I responded to your question on the mapserver-users list)

I should also mention that the full HTML Legend HowTo document lives at: https://mapserver.org/output/html_legend.html

At the bottom of each example page in the HTML Legend demo (https://demo.mapserver.org/itasca_legend/), you will see the template code, which is the contents of the TEMPLATE file referenced in the LEGEND section of the mapfile.

In your case, `mylegend.html` would contain only the following text:

```
[leg_class_html opt_flag=15]
   <img src=[leg_icon]> [leg_class_name]<br>
[/leg_class_html]
```

And your `mylayer.map` would point to that template, within the LEGEND object, such as:

```
# LEGEND object
LEGEND
  STATUS ON
  KEYSIZE 18 12
  # LABEL object
  LABEL
    TYPE BITMAP
    SIZE MEDIUM
    COLOR 0 0 89
  END
  TEMPLATE "mylegend.html"  ### HTML template file
END
```

(you don't need a file named `mylegend.map`)

You can actually test this by using MapServer's `legend` commandline utility (or `legend.exe` if you are using MS4W/Windows).  Call the command to generate your legend image, such as:

```
setenv.bat (for MS4W users)
legend.exe mylayer.map mylegend.png
```

[image]

The full working mapfile and HTML legend files for this demo will soon be included for all MS4W installations, as well (I'm working on the big MS4W 5.0 release, so this makes sense to include).

Comment: Thank you very much, it is very helpful!

Comment: I tried and nothing works for me. I only have a white rectangle with size 35px, 5px.
Do other templates have to exist in the *.map file besides the one in the legend?